# Moshe Grave connected with the Cave of the Patriarchs

Tags: sources-mekorot, avot-patriarch-fathers, moshe-rabbeinu, pentateuch-chumash

The Sefer אישי התנ״ך / the encyclopaedia of biblical personalities brings the sifri Beracha 34:51 “ A tunnel cave connected Moses grave with the graves of the patriarchs.”

I can’t seem to find this. I have Googled the Sifri Beracha and nothing comes up and I have checked on sefaria as well.

Could it be a misprint? If so what is the actual source?

Wishing everyone a Chag Kosher L’Pesach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Sifrei Devarim 357](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifrei_Devarim.357.28?ven=Sifrei_by_Rabbi_Shraga_Silverstein&vhe=Sifrei_Devarim,_Hebrew&lang=bi):

> סמליון אמר: וימת שם משה - מנין אתה אומר, מחילה היתה יוצאה מקבורתו של משה לקבורתן של אבות? נאמר כאן וימת שם משה, ונאמר להלן שמה קברו את אברהם ואת שרה אשתו.
>
> S'malyon said (It called out) "And Moses died there, the great scribe of Israel." Whence is it derived that a tunnel issues from the grave of Moses to that of the patriarchs? It is written here "and Moses died there," and elsewhere, (Bereshith 49:21) "There they buried Abraham and Sarah his wife."